# is MFi chip required for communication with iOS devices over serial port profile (SPP)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, serial-port

Can a classic bluetooth (v2.1) based accessory using Serial Port Profile (SPP)  communicate with all iPhones or iPads ?
  Is MFi chip required by a classic bluetooth(v2.1) accessory to communicate with iPhone or iPad  over Serial Port Profile ?
  Where i can find complete list of standard bluetooth profiles supported by iOS smartphones/tablets ?
  What are all use cases in which MFi chip is required by a bluetooth accessory to communicate with iOS smartphone/tablets ?

Thanks
Pads

Answer (score 1):

Anything other than BTLE requires the MFi. Bluetooth 4.0 is the way to go if you are beginning a new project.

Comment: No, that is only partly correct, because if accessories use standard BT profiles  (over Bluetooth classic v2.x) supported by Apple  to communicate with iOS devices, then they don't have to use MFi chip.                                                     Standard bluetooth profiles supported by iOS is listed here : http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647

Comment: You are correct, although the question involves something custom via SPP so the answer is still the same IMO. http://mfi.apple.com/faqs#4-2

Comment: DCGoD  thanks for response,  I could not understand your response, are you saying that for SPP we still need MFi chip to communicate over bluetooth classic v2.x stack ?

Comment: @user2548414 yes, afaik if you need classib bt 2.1 SPP then you need MFI.